# pandas groupby with custom agg function too slow or uses too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I am running groupby across a 15M row dataframe, grouping by 2 keys (up to 30 chars each) and applying a custom aggregation function that returns multiple values, then writing to CSV.  I have two approaches, one runs out of memory and fails, the other is just too slow (taken over 24 hours to run do far...).  Simplified code is below.

Is there:
- Any way to reduce the memory use of approach 1
or
- any way to speed up the iterator in approach 2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunct(x):
    # test function
    return 1,2,3

# fake the dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1500,3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df['key1'] = np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D','E'], df.shape[0])
df['key2'] = np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D','E'], df.shape[0])

# group and aggregate
grouped = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], sort=False)


#
#  APPROACH 1.
#
# Works but runs out of memory on 15M row datafram with 30 char key1/2
#
f = {'a':['mean', 'count'], 'b':['mean'], 'c':myfunct}
grouped = grouped.aggregate(f)

grouped.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in grouped.columns.values]

#print grouped.head(5)

# split out columns - expensive?
grouped[['c_myfunct_1', 'c_myfunct_2', 'c_myfunct_3']] = grouped['c_myfunct'].apply(pd.Series)
grouped.drop('c_myfunct', axis=1, inplace=True)

#print grouped.head(5)

# write to file
grouped.to_csv('test1.csv')


#
#    APPROACH 2.
#
# Alternate approach works fine but extremely slow!
#
grouped_again = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], sort=False)

header_ = True

with open('test2.csv', 'a') as f:

    for keys, group in grouped_again:

        (k1, k2) = keys
        temp_df = df.loc[(df['key1'] == k1) & (df['key2'] == k2)].groupby(['key1', 'key2'], sort=False)
        temp_df = temp_df.aggregate({'a':['mean', 'count'], 'b':['mean'], 'c':myfunct})
        temp_df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in temp_df.columns.values]

        if header_ == True:
            temp_df.to_csv(f, float_format='%.3f', header = header_)
            header_ = False

        else:
            temp_df.to_csv(f, float_format='%.3f', header = header_)
```

Comment: Just tested the approach 1 with your code and 15M rows and it works fine. I think this is the right way to do that. I suspect the problem comes from the custom function.

Comment: Thanks for testing.  I switched in my custom function with the above code and it's still extremely fast.  I don't think the custom function is a problem.  After testing it some more the problem seems to lie in the groupby working against a very large number of distinct keys.  I'll see if I can get some different test code that isolates this problem instead.

Comment: Yeah, when groupby is slow it's usually related to a large number of distinct groups which is not how you have your sample data set up.  You might want to use range in combo with np.tile or np.repeat to get lots of groups.  Also you might want to make myfunct a little more realistic as it doesn't do any actual aggregation as written.  May not matter but as written you don't even need to run it through the groupby so hard do test what it's doing.